# Converting GetDate() to current date with a specific time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to figure out a way to convert GetDate() to send me results only from the current date and between the time of 08:15 and 09:00, the purpose of this query is to find out exactly which employees logged into the system between those times but every time I attempt to alter the code in order to send me the current date I am receiving errors.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=GTX-COMSVR2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Att;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=********";
    //con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], USERINFO.NAME [Name], CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME [Clock Time], CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE [I/O], CHECKINOUT.SENSORID [Sensor ID] FROM USERINFO, CHECKINOUT WHERE USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID and CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE = 'I' and CHECKINOUT.SENSORID = '1' and CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= ('04/01/2014 08:15') and CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME <= ('04/01/2014 09:00') ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC ", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

As you can see from the code above I am yet to implement the GetDate() function as every time I do I am receiving errors and I wish for my program to run as smoothly as possible.

Any help with be much appreciated and up voted, I currently have one years experience on and off programming within the C# environment so I understand how to resolve many issues but have trouble implementing the correct code when working with SQL Server.

Thanks people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass in the desired `DateTime` values as parameters from your C# code?

Change the code into this:

```
DateTime startTime = ...;
DateTime endTime = ...;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE .. AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN @startTime and @endTime ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC ", con))
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", startTime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", endTime);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Set `startTime` and `endTime` in your C# code to the date/time you actually want to query. For example:

```
startTime = new DateTime(2014, 04, 02, 08, 15, 0);
endTime = new DateTime(2014, 04, 02, 09, 0, 0);
```

or

```
startTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(15);
endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(45);
```

---

As requested, this is how your code would look:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"..."; 

    //Query all entries between 08:15 and 09:00 today
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(15);
    DateTime endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(45);

    // I use "using" to make sure command and data adapter are disposed of automatically
    // I use a separate command so I can add the parameters more easily.
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE .. AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN @startTime and @endTime ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC ", con))
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        // Pass in the two parameters to the query (note: I don't have to take care
        // of any formatting here - aren't parameterized queries a treat? :-)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", startTime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", endTime);

        // Keep doing what you did before
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show me this example using my code as stated in the question please so I can understand how this will work more (sorry I'm on my third coffee now)

Comment: Of course, I will edit my answer :-) Grab another coffee and wait a second :-D

Answer (score 0):

Should just be:

```
CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20140401',GETDATE(),
                                                 '2014-04-01T08:15:00') and
CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20140401',GETDATE(),
                                                '2014-04-01T09:00:00')
```

I've also switched to using `<` for the end point, since this is usually actually what's wanted (you'd usually want events that happen strictly *before* 9am, and to exclude events that occur *at* 9am)

You don't change the date literals. The only important thing is about the relationship between them. So, we first work out "how many complete days elapsed between 1st April 2014 and the current datetime" and then we add that same number of days onto 1st April 2014 at 08:15 - with the net result being that we've calculated today's date at 08:15.

Comment: are you missing '=' on the third line of code or is that correct syntax?

Comment: @MrBrownDXB - I did try to highlight, just below the code, *why* I'd changed from doing a `<=` comparison to a `<` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())) AS Today
     ) AS CA1
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DATEADD(minute, 8*60+15, Today) AS StartTime
               ,DATEADD(minute, 9*60, Today) AS EndTime
     ) AS CA2
WHERE CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

IF it is SQL SERVER 2008 or Above

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME  
SELECT @CurrentDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

SELECT 
    USERINFO.USERID [User ID], 
    USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], 
    USERINFO.NAME [Name], 
    CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME [Clock Time], 
    CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE [I/O], 
    CHECKINOUT.SENSORID [Sensor ID] 
FROM 
    USERINFO, 
    CHECKINOUT 
WHERE 
    USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
    AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE = 'I' 
    AND CHECKINOUT.SENSORID = '1' 
    AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN (DATEADD (MINUTE, 495, @CurrentDate) AND DATEADD (MINUTE, 540, @CurrentDate))) 
ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC
```

--OR--

```
SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], USERINFO.NAME [Name], CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME [Clock Time], CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE [I/O], CHECKINOUT.SENSORID [Sensor ID] FROM USERINFO, CHECKINOUT WHERE USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE = 'I' AND CHECKINOUT.SENSORID = '1' AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN DATEADD (MINUTE, 495, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) AND DATEADD (MINUTE, 540, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))))) ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

this should work for you. All the best

```
SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], USERINFO.NAME [Name], CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME [Clock Time], CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE [I/O], CHECKINOUT.SENSORID [Sensor ID] 
FROM USERINFO, CHECKINOUT 
WHERE USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
    and CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE = 'I' 
    and CHECKINOUT.SENSORID = '1' 
    and CONVERT(varchar,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,101) = CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
    and CONVERT(varchar, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,108) BETWEEN '08:15:00' AND '09:00:00'
ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC
```

Comment: This isn't a good style to follow because converting the column values to strings completely destroys any possibility of the server being able to use any index.